# Cannot login after partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, login

I‘m on a dualboot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 19.10. I tried to assign more storage to my ubuntu partition: I shrank the windows partition in GParted. Then I did a reboot. After that I tried to login to Ubuntu. After a short black screen I always return to the login screen. Hence I cannot login to ubuntu. What is the problem? How can I log back in without reinstalling ubuntu?

**More details** (listing everything I did before and since the problem occurred):

- I downloaded lutris (without any error).
- I shrank the windows partition (Please ignore my more than naive approach to partitioning; still a noob).
- Reboot —> Login didn‘t work —> windows login worked —> reboot —> ubuntu login still didn‘t work.
- System details: Lenovo Yoga 260, Dualboot Windows10/Ubuntu19.10, lightdm.

**What I‘ve tried**:

- Checked permissions for Xauthority which were fine.
- Switched login manager to see whether the problem is due to lightdm (see [Ubuntu login-loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)).
- Logged into console (Ctrl + Alt + F3) and then started desktop with „sudo startx“ which started a session as root but didn‘t give me access to my home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Here's the procedure I followed:

1. I created a bootable live usb and started an install session.
2. When the installer asked about the installation type I clicked "Something else" which brought me to the partitioning screen.
3. I then created a 300MB EFI Primary Partition.
4. After that I aborted the installation process and rebooted.
   --> Problem solved.

I then solved my the first problem (assigning more storage to ubuntu) by following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/1QjQ4q5kcVs).